# i missed my salah for yesterday and today - can I read them as qaza together?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

assalaamu alaikum warah matullahi wabarkaatu. bro could please help me in answering my questions for salah, i’ve Tried searching for some help on the internet and it’s onky made me more confused, my question is I wasn’t able to read all my 5 salah yesterday and I wasn’t able to read fair, zuhr, asr and maghrib. I’m planning onto reading isha rn would I be able to read qaza namaz for my missed salah for today and yesterday together or is there any other way?

Comment: Please tap on the added tag and you may find answers addressing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Wa alaikum salaam wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh

sounds like you missed 8 consecutive salah, right? In that case you can read them whenever you like, provided it's not makruh time. The ruling is different if you had missed less than 5.

This is according to Hanafi. Rulings may differ for other madhabs.